# Complex regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a generic pattern using regex so that it fetches only particular things from the string. Let's say we have strings like GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0 or FastEthernet0/4 or Ethernet0/0.222. The regex should fetch the first 2 characters and all the numerals. Therefore, the fetched result should be something like Gi0000 or Fa04 or Et00222 depending on the above cases.

```
x = 'GigabitEthernet0/0/0/2
m = re.search('([\w+]{2}?)[\\\.(\d+)]{0,}',x)
```

I am not able to understand how shall I write the regular expression. The values can be fetched in the form of a list also. I write few more patterns but it isn't helping.

Comment: If you're going to process a lot of strings you should [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) your regex - it's a lot more efficient than creating the same regex over & over in a loop.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you very much, it would be of great help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regex, you may use `re.findall` function.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0 '
>>> s[:2]+''.join(re.findall(r'\d', s))
'Gi0000'
```

OR

```
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'^..|\d', s))
'Gi0000'
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'^..|\d', 'Ethernet0/0.222'))
'Et00222'
```

OR

```
>>> s = 'GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0 '
>>> s[:2]+''.join([i for i in s if i.isdigit()])
'Gi0000'
```

Comment: you can use `s[:2]` and a list comprehension within `join` for more performance

Comment: Now you just need to turn that last gen exp into a list comp. :) As Kasra said, you get better performance that way. That's because `join` has to scan its iterable arg twice - the 1st scan is to determine the size of the string it needs to allocate. So if you pass it a generator it has to build that into a list before it can join it.

Comment: Lots of people don't know that. :) So I'll leave that comment for the benefit of future readers, even though you've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
z="Ethernet0/0.222."
print z[:2]+"".join(re.findall(r"(\d+)(?=[\d\W]*$)",z))
```

You can try this.This will make sure only digits from end come into play .

Comment: But from the OP it looks like Vipul wants all the digits, eg `Ethernet0/0.222` -> `Et00222`

Comment: @PM2Ring `Gig9abitEthernet0/0/0/2` i dont think OP would want `9` from this ex..He should clarify though

Comment: @Vipul what is the expected output for `Gig9abitEthernet0/0/0/2` do you want `9` here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```py
s = 'Ethernet0/0.222'

"".join(re.findall('^\w{2}|[\d]+', s))
```